# Access inline js object in an external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an inline js object that I'm trying to access in an external js file like so:

**inline js:**

```
      <script type="text/javascript">  
          $(function(){ 
               var person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46};
          });
     </script>
```

**external js:**

```
$(function() {
    var name = person.firstName;
});
```

When I run this code I get a js error saying person is not defined.The external file is called after the inline js. The inline js is at the top of the page and the external js is link at the bottom of the page like so:

```
<script src = "js/example.js"></script>
```

Can anyone add some insight to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I figured out how to do this. First the jsp  I added an empty array like so:

```
<script>
    window.names= [];
</script>
```

Then in the for each loop in the jsp i populated the empty array like so (this method is for a dynamic list that is coming back from your controller):

```
        <script>
            window.names.push({
                names: '${name.allNames}'
            });
        </script>
```

if your list is not dynamic you can do something like this:

```
    <script>
        window.names.push({
            names: '${ken, james, jen, emily}'
        });
    </script>
```

Then in your external js you can access the list like so:

```
(function( detail, $, undefined, index) {
        'use strict';
        var names= detail[0].allNames;
})(names, jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple scope issue. You're declaring `person` *inside* of the function. Outside of that function, you can't access `person`. See an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/7ksaethr/1/

To fix this, declare `person` outside of the function, and then set it within:

```
var person = null;
$(function(){ 
    person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46};
});
```

```
$(function() {
    var name = person.firstName;
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/7ksaethr/2/

Comment: I'm unsure as to why you've downvoted me. My answer is not incorrect, you've just provided the alternative solution of not providing an implicit scope. If you prefer to do it this way, then provide your own answer.

Comment: Thanks but person is declared in the dom, in the first piece of js script. And i was not the one who downvoted you...

Comment: You are misunderstanding @vslat. If you declare a variable using `var` inside of a function, *it will only be accessible **inside** of that function*. You have to declare it *outside* of the function, as I have in my example. An alternative would be to not use `var` when declaring it, as this instantiates the variable within the current scope.

Comment: I see where you are coming from, I will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: @Santi i'm sorry but you're misunderstanding..  the function in the OP is a ready function shortcut `$(function(){})`.. so your answer become Unnecessary :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at the [`scope`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) concept and how javascript implements it.

By the way, 
in your case the `person` variable is declared inside the `anonymous callback` passed as parameter into the `$()` function, so, only that scope and their children-scopes can access to that variable.

1. because that `variable` is **private**, you need to expose it to its parent scope: `window.person` instead of `var person`.
2. Because that `variable` is declared in a callback you need to wait `jQuery` to fire it before trying to access to `person`.

```js
$(function() {
  window.person = { name: 'Giuseppe' };
});

// this should log undefined
console.log('person is not defined yet', window.person);

$(function() {
  console.log('person', window.person);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```